# How to remove just a part of a string in a data frame in R?

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I would like to remove part of a string from a V2 column in a `df`.

```
df 
   V1     V2
    3  scale_KD_1
   10  scale_KD_5
    4  scale_KD_10
    7  scale_KD_7
```

The desired outcome would be:

```
df 
 
     V1     V2
      3      1
     10      5
      4     10
      7      7
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sub` to remove everything until `_`:

```
df$V2 <- sub(".*_", "", df$V2)
#df$V2 <- sub("\\D*", "", df$V2)  #Some Alternatives
#df$V2 <- sub("[^[:digit:]]*", "", df$V2)
df
#  V1 V2
#1  3  1
#2 10  5
#3  4 10
#4  7  7
```

Data:

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text="   V1     V2
    3  scale_KD_1
   10  scale_KD_5
    4  scale_KD_10
    7  scale_KD_7")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using readr and stringr packages:

```
library(readr)
df %>% mutate(V2 = parse_number(V2))
  V1 V2
1  3  1
2 10  5
3  4 10
4  7  7
library(stringr)
df %>% mutate(V2 = str_remove(V2, '.*_'))
  V1 V2
1  3  1
2 10  5
3  4 10
4  7  7
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to accomplish this. Just check which one is faster. Besides the ones mentioned by @Karthik S, you can try these ones:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

 df %>% 
  mutate(V2 = str_extract(V2, '\\d+$'))
 

df %>% 
  mutate(V2 = str_remove(V2, '\\D+'))


  V1 V2
1  3  1
2 10  5
3  4 10
4  7  7
```